# Como acessar uma variável de uma função em outra função

Tags: php, cakephp

Digamos que tenho a função

```
public function testeX(){
    $x = 1;
    $this->set('x', $x);
}
```

E eu quero acessar o valor de x em outra function que tem uma view *testeY.ctp*

```
public function testeY(){ // Esta é minha view
    //Como faria pra acessar a variavel $x aqui ?
}
```

Eu quero apenas acessar o valor de $x na minha view testeY... Pois é o valor de $x que tem o resultado da minha busca que será mostrada em um modal. Irei percorrer o valor de $x para colocar em seus respectivos campos.

Comment: Ambos são métodos de uma mesma classe? Digo isso por causa do `$this` na primeira função.

Comment: Ambos estão no mesmo controller.

Answer (score 1):

**No CakePHP versão 1.2.x:**

```
$vars = ClassRegistry::getObject('view') -> viewVars;
echo $vars['x']; // o nome do índice é o nome da variável que deseja acessar.
```

Para usar é necessário extender o helper

```
class NomeDaClasse extends AppHelper {
```

**A partir da versão 2:**

```
$this->_View->viewVars['x']; // o nome do índice é o nome da variável que deseja acessar.
```

**Para a versão 1**

Apesar de irrelevante pois dificilmente alguém ainda usa a versão 1 atualmente, 
segue a mesma forma da versão 1.2.x, apenas modificando o atributo `viewVars` para `passedArgs`

```
ClassRegistry::getObject('view')->passedArgs;
```

Comment: `$this->_View->viewVars['x'];` Eu apenas mudaria o 'x' pela variável que desejo acessar na view né ? O restante da syntax é padrão. Vou ler sobre isso.

Comment: Não exatamente pois viewVars retorna os índices gerados pelo set(). Exemplo:  $this->set('x', $x ). Entendeu? Leia a documentação do CakePHP.